# How can I make my .exrc script work only for specific files extension?

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

I made a script to turn my vim into a IDE for C language via the .exrc script. The problem is that this latter, the .exrc file, works for any kind of file opened with vim editor. So my question here: Is it possible to make a restriction on the script for some files with c extension or run the .exrc file for only a specific directory !

I also read a book about vim and it says:

"**You can also set up .exrc files in local directories to initialize various options that you want to use in different environments. For example, you might define one set of options for editing English text, but another set for editing source programs. The .exrc file in your home directory will be executed first, then the one in your current directory.** "

but it never worked for me !! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `.exrc`, you can have directory-specific configuration. What you've read in that book probably assumes that you've segregated your different files into different directories.

To differentiate different filetypes, you can set up autocmds on the `FileType` event in your `.exrc` file (just like some do globally in their `~/.vimrc`, as an alternative to the `~/.vim/ftplugin/` method), e.g.:

```
:autocmd FileType c setlocal expandtab
```

#### Plugin alternative

Instead of `.exrc`, the [localrc.vim - Enable configuration file of each directory](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3393) plugin provides sourcing of filetype-specific configuration via separate files (configurable via `g:localrc_filetype`), which makes the setup very easy and convenient. I've improved the filetype handling on [this branch in my fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-localrc/commits/enhancements).

Comment: I created a .vimrc file then wrote **autocmd FileType c /Path of the script/** ( The .exrc need to be changed from the home directory so it can has a restricted effect ) and it worked like a charm ! Thanks :D !!